# Using multiple projects of Firebase- Ionic 2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I would like to create a multi idiom app with firebase, each app will have its own firebase project, but I would like to share among all of them one firebase project, because each app will need to need comun information, for example I want to make the login with the central firebase.
So if I can include the information of two projects in one app, it will be the solution, but I don't know if it is possible.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access two Firebase projects from a single web app, you'll need to include the configuration for both in your code:

```
var secondaryAppConfig = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
```

Then you initialize a secondary app instance and retrieve the database (or other Firebase service you want to use):

```
// Initialize another app with a different config
var secondary = firebase.initializeApp(secondaryAppConfig, "secondary");

// Retrieve the database.
var secondaryDatabase = secondary.database();
```

See the [Firebase documentation for using multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application).

Comment: Thank you Frank for your answer, but can I use a single app with 2 Firebase projects?

Comment: Ah, the other way around. :-) That is also possible. See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application

Comment: Thank you very much!, I am a begginer so sorry if I ask you too much.